# SSH commands - cleared console without any error/message

Tags: ssh, console

I have Kubuntu 22.04 and I have some troubles with SSH output in a console. Every SSH command clears console. I even can't check a version of SSH.
For instance, this is what I type:

```
admin@machine:~$ssh -V
```

And this is a result:

```
admin@machine:~$
```

with cleared all previous text. And this is how it behaves for any SSH command (except those which succeed to connect to a remote host).

I searched for similar problems, but I didn'ŧ find anything relevant. I though I have maybe set wrong LogLevel, so I tried to set it to INFO:
`ssh -o LogLevel=INFO`
but again I got cleared console without any output.
Also verbose options have no impact, I can't debug anything regarding SSH.

But when I connect to a remote host, SSH command works as expected (on the remote host). But as soon as I quit the connection by Ctrl+D, I'm getting cleared console again.

Does anybody know what can be reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much guys for your effort and advices. I finally found a problem in `.bash_aliases`, this piece:

```bash
setterm -default -clear rest;
```

I really don't know how could it appear in aliases, but after I removed it, it started to work as expected. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your shell startup files for the commands that set your prompt (`admin@machine:~`).  I think one of them is telling your terminal to clear its display before showing the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I are you running **Konsole** as your console? If so it has it's own Plugin for SSH. You don't have to use it, but it may be useful if you are going to use SSH a lot. Also, **Konsole** is different than most basic terminals, check the options closely as well as checking what @Sotto Voce said with `cat .bashrc` or `cat .zshrc`.

Comment: Yes, I do use **Konsole**. I checked .bashrc, but I didn't find anything related to this. I have another machine with Kubuntu 22.04 and I tried co check .bashrc, but they are both the same.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one more thing. I tried to run:

```
source .bashrc
```

And subsequently run a `ssh` command. This leads to an error:

```
Warning: Program 'bash' crashed.
```

This error is shown after any ssh command, even `ssh -V`.
But then when I close Konsole, re-open it and try any ssh command, I'm getting cleared console without any message again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have a **`.zshrc`** file located in the same place as your **`.bashrc`** file? Your default shell could be **zsh**.

I found similar Q&As on StackOverFlow (in the wrong place lol):

I have a feel that this should help you fix the issue.

[Stack: Bash commands not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437084/cant-execute-any-basic-command-in-linux-console)